# Flutter: packages not added into flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

We are working on `Flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.4`, using `VS Code` added a new package called `english_words`. the package is updated with all required files in the app but SDK, not updated `flutter/packages`, here we are unable to see the package folder.

Due to the above issues getting an error from `main.dart` file

```
Target of URI doesn't exist 'package:english_words/english_words.dart'.
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

- run `flutter packages get` got response `exit code 0`
- run `flutter pub get` or `pub get` no error.
- `reload/rebuild` the app using `flutter run` but packages not updated.
- `pubspec.yaml`, `pubspec.lock`, `.packages` updated fine.
- tried from VS Code Tool click `get Packages` not solved.

Comment: Can you share the content of your pubspec ?

Comment: @Muldec- Yes, We updated our code with `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Check answer, pls

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky - Same bug. package not added to `flutter/packages` and gettign error message in `main.dart`

Comment: Tried to add from VS Code `get Packages` then also same.

Comment: Read more carefully. Did you just change `dev_dependencies` to `dependencies`?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky - Nope: removed package under the `dev_dependencies` and added under `dependencies`

Comment: But why there is `flutter_test` in your pasted code? It has to be `flutter`

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this in your `pubsec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

In you code there is `dev_dependencies`. Replace this dependency